# EventGridPublisherClient SendEventAsync doesnt throw error when topic doesnt exists under Event grid domain

Tags: c#, events, grid, azure-eventgrid

Why doesn't EventGridPublisherClient SendEventAsync doesnt throw error when topic doesnt exist under Event grid domain. it returns 200 and I see the message in Event Grid domain, which topic it will go if the particular topic doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Event Grid is a *loosely decoupled* Pub/Sub eventing push model.
Based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains#domain-scope-subscriptions), the event domains also allow for domain-scope subscriptions, so all events are sent also to the "none topic" such as a domain scope.

**Update:**

You can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane-version2021-10-15-preview/domain-topics/get) for query a domain topic, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

in the case, when the topic is not exists (for instance: topic123456), the error is returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Domain topic topic123456 under Domain myDomain is not found. Please check the domain topic name and try again."
  }
}
```

Comment: Nt sure if i was clear enough, my question is if I dont have topic create in Event Grid Domain and while sending if i specfiy the topic which doesnt exists than where will the event go? e,g, If I publish event to topic called "test" while that topic doesnt exist than where will that event go?

Comment: Basically, there are two cases: **1.** no domain scope subscription, the event published on the domain topic *test* will be not distributed (there is no a consumer - interest for that event message). **2.** there is a domain scope subscription, this event message will be distributed to the destination event handler declared in this domain scope subscription.

Comment: What I am asking is that there is a topic inside Event Grid domain and if there is any way that while publishing events to Event Grid domain we can check either topic exists or not or it errors out.

Comment: @Punit, see my update

Comment: Thanks @Roman Kiss I figured out some time back using EventManagnementClient classs, do you know if there are retry policy can be implemented for EventGridPublisherClient, I can use Polly and able to setup on HttpRequestException but unable to do on 429 error because SDK doesn't return HttpResponseMessage.